Show that the level set of the sum of a continuous and a semicontinuous function is closed.
Let $$E_{\alpha} = \{z \in \mathbb{R} : zt - \log(\varphi(t)) \leq \alpha\}$$ be the level sets of $Q_t(z) =  zt - \log(\varphi(t))$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, with $\alpha \in [0, \infty)$. I`ve already verified that $\log(\varphi(t))$ is lower semi-continuous, and that $zt$ is continuous. How to prove that $E_{\alpha}$ is closed?
My initial try was to follow the approach made in:
Sum of LSC functions also LSC function
So, my idea was to prove that $E_{\alpha}^c$ is open, therefore, $E_{\alpha}$ is closed.
\begin{align*}
     \{z \in \mathbb{R} :  zt - log(\varphi(t)) > c\} &=  \{z \in \mathbb{R} :  zt >    log(\varphi(t))  +c\}\\
&= \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}\{z \in \mathbb{R} :  zt > r >   log(\varphi(t))  +c\}\\
&=\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}\{z \in \mathbb{R} :  zt > r \} \cap \{ z\in \mathbb{R} :   log(\varphi(t)) < r  -c\}\\
&=\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}\{z \in \mathbb{R} :  zt > r \} \cap \{  z\in \mathbb{R} :   log(\varphi(t)) < r  -c\}\\
\end{align*}
Since $log(\varphi(t))$ is semi-continuous, it follows that  $\{ z \in \mathbb{R} :   log(\varphi(t)) < r  +c\}$ is closed and since $zt$ is continuous, it follows that $\{  z\in \mathbb{R} :   zt > r\}$ is open.
On Sum of LSC functions also LSC function, they ended up finding the intersection between two open sets that is clearly an open set. But in my case I have an intersection of an open set and a closed set, which can be open, closed or neither.
Another tentative was to use Sum of two upper semi continuous functions is upper semi continuous. Since $\log(\phi(t))$ is lower semi-continuous, so $-\log(\phi(t))$ will be upper semi-continuous, and as $zt$ is continuous, so it will also be upper semi-continuous, and finally the sum will be upper semi-continuous too.
I don't know if I am doing something wrong or missing something and forgive me if I made some terrible mistake, I`m a beginner in this field.
